# Why cant I append a character in the 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to append a value q at certain position of the 2d array using numpy
but I get an error at
line of code is:
 **`a[r,c]='Q'`** as

> *ValueError: could not convert string to float: Q*

```
#!/bin/python

import sys
import numpy as np
#n=int(raw_input())


n,k = raw_input().strip().split(' ')

n,k = [int(n),int(k)]

a=np.zeros((n,n))
r,c = raw_input().strip().split(' ')

r,c = [int(r)-1,int(c)-1]

a[r,c]='Q'  # ValueError: could not convert string to float: Q

print a
```

Comment: 'Q' is a string. Your array is numerical, so it can't take a string. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: So i have an input with coordinate numbers.Here r and c is the coordinate position where i need to place a character Q.You could skip the for loop section...those have some different functionality.The only thing I wanted to do is to set a character in the numpy array given its coordinates.

Comment: You could try an object array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html 
But if you need to store numbers and strings in the same structure, that's a strong indication that a Numpy array isn't the right tool for the job (or that you don't actually need to store them in the same structure).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place characters into an array you need an array that takes data of character or string type. The default data type in numpy arrays is floating point, which is not compatible with strings. Hence the error message.

Setting data type to `<U1` (unicode) or `<S1` (byte string) will tell numpy that the array takes strings of length one (i.e. a character) or an empty string:

```
a = np.zeros((3, 4), dtype='<U1')
a[1, 2] = 'Q'
print(a)
# [['' '' '' '']
#  ['' '' 'Q' '']
#  ['' '' '' '']]
```

Note that if you try to insert a longer string (`a[0, 0] = 'ABC'`) it will only take the first character. If you insert a number the number will be converted to string and only the first character inserted (`a[0, 0] = 42` -> `'4'`).

Comment: This is the output:[[u'' u'' u'' u'' u'']
 [u'' u'' u'1' u'' u'']
 [u'' u'' u'' u'' u'']
 [u'' u'1' u'Q' u'' u'']
 [u'' u'' u'' u'' u'1']]

Comment: how do i remove the u's

Comment: Ah, you're on Python 2 :) Then use `dtype='<S1'`. The u's just indicate that these are unicode strings.